# Drop in kitchen sink to replace an under mount

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-sink

I'm looking to replace our current stainless steel under mount kitchen sink with a drop in cast iron.

The current sink is 22 x 33 as is the new installed sink (22 x 33).
In order to remove the existing sink, the bull nose tiles on all four sides of the current sink need to be removed (there are no claps under the current sink to be removed to assist with taking it out).

I can remove the tiles easily, as that is not the issue.  However, in order to put in the new sink there will be an inch excess gap on all four sides of the sink - where they bull nose tiles are.
Do I have to retile all four sides in order to place the new sink in?
Is there an alternative way to by pass re-tiling prior to installing the new sink (plywood strips), etc.?

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Our kitchen countertops are in pristine condition and we would like to keep them in tact.

As well, we are in love with the new sink and replacing it with a different one is not what we are considering.

Comment: If the stainless steel sink is truly an under mount why are you unable to remove its mounts and take it out from below?

Comment: If the bull nose tiles were left in place is the opening from side to side and front to back between the bull nose big enough to allow the new drop in sink to fit?

Comment: I ask the above because it sounds kind of like the stainless steel sink originally installed from the top and hung from a lip. Later tile and bull nose were installed over the lip of the stainless steel sink. If I am right then you may be able to consider sawing out the old sink in such a way that you leave the old hang lip in place under the bull nose tile. Such process could be done carefully using cutoff disks with a dremel tool and a lot of time. However if the nose to nose dimensions are too small for the new sink then you are going to have no choice but to do some re-tiling.

Comment: Michael - Thank you for getting back to me.  The current sink is an under mount but no clamps underneath.  If the bull nose tiles were left in place the space would be a perfect fit for the new drop in sink.  And yes, you are correct in that the sink looks like it was installed from the top and hung from a lip and then later tiled and bull nose were installed.   Will using cutoff disk and a Dremel tool cause any sparks considering we'd be using it to cut a stainless steel sink?  Can you think of any other way this can be done safely and quickly?  Maybe move the bullnose and add plywood strips?

Comment: Or alternative way in lieu of re-tiling?  Thanks again!

Comment: @JenniferJohnson - I would not recommend trying to kludge in "plywood strips" around the sides of your sink. The wood totally defeats the water resistant features of the tile and in my opinion would be ugly as all the dickens. Cutting out with the Dremel tool and cut-off wheels is recommended because it offers the best chance at fine control of the cutting process without disturbance of the lip that is under the bull nose tile. Some larger tool could disturb the lip and break loose those existing tiles. Cutting with the Dremel will create red hot metal debris as the grinding (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) process proceeds but it cools quickly. Make sure to wear eye protection and absolutely and firmly support the old sink from below so that it does not drop near the end of the cutting and disturb part of the remaining lip. One last concern. Make really sure that the new sink would drop into the hole left by the cut out sink. Normally the hole for a drop in sink is made larger by some amount so that the sink position can be scootched around to allow it to be aligned square with the counter top. Last thing you want is for the sides of the new sink to bind in the hole.

Comment: I really appreciate all the information Michael.  Thank you for taking time to do so.  After reading your comments, I think we've opted to take out the bull nose tile around the sink in order to take out the current sink, retile the surrounding area, and then install the new drop in sink. It might take longer, but I think it will the most ideal way to go.  Thank you again for all your time!

Comment: We're redoing our kitchen and had settled on an undermount sink.  Just would like to know if you are changing because you ran into problems with the undermount?

Answer (score 1):

I use razorblade 27 abrasive cutting disks on a 4" grinder . razorblade is a brand that holds up well but there are others very thin metal cutting blades that will do the job in minutes, yes on sparks but I have never started a fire and have cut every kind of metal with this method. I just measured a disk and they are 0.075" thick.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sterling sink, and drop over the existing hole. Cut out the stainless sink about a 1/4" from the tile. But first 
go to Home Depot and order your sterling sink so it will cover the hole, before you make the hole. Wifes sister did their sink and loved it. We did remove our under the counter sink in our bathroom and put in the sterling we ordered in advance from Home Depot. We love it![image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the pictures, it looks fantastic and clean job.  What did you use to cut out the old sink with?